How to get all energy values in qiskit in the vibrational tutorial
I am running the vibrational turorial for CO2: 02_vibrational_structure.ipynb https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-nature/tutorials/02_vibrational_structure.html I use it with the standard input logfile for CO2. The result is * Vibrational ground state energy (cm^-1): 2432.106954036547. This is the energy value for the assymmetric stretch or v3 of CO2. However there are more eigenvalues in case of  CO2, like symmetrical stretch the value 1330 1/cm. Can I get these values by setting the filter_criterion()?
Some context for this question:
CO2 has a powerful heat-trapping effect, it is caused by the fermi resonance of two types of motion in the molecule. It is a combination of bending and symmetrical stretch in the molecule. More information can be found here.

What is the procedure for finding the vibrational frequencies?
First we need a Gausian Force driver, this file contains all information regarding the molecule. The info is read from this file.
from qiskit_nature.second_q.drivers import GaussianForcesDriver
# if you ran Gaussian elsewhere and already have the output 
driver = GaussianForcesDriver(logfile="CO2_freq_B3LYP_631g.log")

Then we need to setup a basis to run the simulation.
Last step is run the simulation.
from qiskit_algorithms import NumPyMinimumEigensolver           
from qiskit_nature.second_q.algorithms import GroundStateEigensolver                                            
solver = GroundStateEigensolver(
qubit_mapper,
NumPyMinimumEigensolver(filter_criterion=vibrational_problem.get_default_filter_criterion()),
)                                                             
result = solver.solve(vibrational_problem)             
print(result)

The filter_criterion uses a default setting. So we need a similar method for showing other eigenvalues. To get started we can print the
the varable used for defining the filter.
 def filter_criterion(self, eigenstate, eigenvalue, aux_values):
        
        for mode, _ in enumerate(self.num_modals):
            if aux_values is None or not np.isclose(aux_values[str(mode)][0], 1):
                print(aux_values[str(mode)][0])
                return False
        
        return True

    return partial(filter_criterion, self)

To test the code you need two files:
The vibrational tutorial and the CO2 log file.
Both files can be found in the qiskit eco system in github
Furthermore you need qiskit (ofcourse), qiskit-nature and qiskit-algorithms.

Can you please directly put your code in your post rather than using a link? Something short that can be used to test and modify your code

To test the code you will probably need the whole tutorial for good understanding what is going on.

@Bram if you're going to refuse the request from a diamond moderator (or any other experienced user with a more than reasonable request), I am okay with issuing the 4th close vote here.

After a more detailed inspection, it looks like you did add the code, but made a comment that suggested that you didn't. You also already answered the question, so I'm voting to keep this open.

I solved the first part of the problem. One can get all the eigenvalues with a simple print statement in the filter methode of the class VibrationalStructureProblem()

def filter_criterion(self, eigenstate, eigenvalue, aux_values):

        def filter_criterion(self, eigenstate, eigenvalue, aux_values): 
          for mode, _ in enumerate(self.num_modals):
            if aux_values is None or not np.isclose(aux_values[str(mode)][0], 1):
                **print(aux_values[str(mode)][0], eigenvalue)**
                return False
        
        print(aux_values[str(mode)][0])
        return True

    return partial(filter_criterion, selfBlockquote

This will output all the values.
0.0 -2.6147972675971687e-12
0.0 238.31540749999692
0.0 238.31540749999715
0.0 483.7291649999968
0.0 704.3670941150175
0.0 728.9613774999975
0.0 728.961377499998
0.0 939.9765053389528
0.0 939.9765053389548
0.0 967.2767849999973
0.0 967.2767849999977
0.0 988.571834999997
0.0 988.5718349999975
0.0 1180.0982241817762
0.0 1233.985592499997
0.0 1233.9855924999974
0.0 1268.0676746874974
0.0 1417.4180044195143
0.0 1417.4180044195143
0.0 1496.177190937496
0.0 1496.177190937497
0.0 1521.8079049999983
0.0 1645.1952501161295
0.0 1645.1952501161304
0.0 1666.4903001161306
0.0 1666.490300116132
0.0 1731.3850571874973
0.0 1781.4183624999978
0.0 1781.4183624999987
0.0 1898.764140513612
0.0 1898.764140513612
0.0 1966.3328486690132
0.0 1966.4113784374972
0.0 1966.4113784374972
0.0 2048.127169999998
0.0 2121.6108471349785
0.0 2170.8967503261147
0.0 2194.5208946874973
0.0 2194.5208946874973
0.0 2196.892963254387
0.0 2196.8929632543877
0.0 2215.8159446874974
0.0 2215.815944687498
0.0 2345.855053411041
0.0 2345.8550534110423
0.0 2412.344924736852
0.0 2412.344924736853
(1.0000000000000007+0j)
=== GROUND STATE ===

Vibrational ground state energy (cm^-1): 2432.10695403655

I can pick the right one, however I would like to have a solid criterion for that. So there is still some finetuning needed.

What do you mean by the "right one"? If you could access all the eigenvalues directly in a numpy array, would that work for you? Or do you specifically want to use the filter_criterion so that it returns the second lowest eigenvalue?

The right eigenvalues are already known from classical calculation, for example: https://education.molssi.org/qm-tools/04-vib-freq/index.html. We can compare classical and quantum results.  However it would be nice to have a criterion that defines the right values. So maybe the question has a physics part in it: how to define the right answer and then how to implement.

This is the comment I got from Qiskit slack and might be helpful:
For that tutorial its using the numpy eigen solver which, without any filter criteria will return all eigenvalues it finds. You can read/see what the default one does from its API ref documentation. You can certainly change the filter and allow it to return all the values that it finds - I do not know how exactly the problem operator is built etc to know whether you will find what you are looking for or not though.
